# PHP library object error

Tags: php, imagick

I am having an issue with `imagick` php library.

I am doing a recursive search in my file system and look for any `pdf` files.

```
    $it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/test/project");
    $display = Array ('pdf');
    foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file){
        if (in_array(strtolower(array_pop(explode('.', $file))), $display))
        {
            if(file_exists($file)){
                echo $file;     //this would echo /test/project/test1.pdf
                $im = new Imagick($file);
                $im->setImageFormat("jpg");

                file_put_contents('test.txt', $im);
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I am getting an error saying

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Can not process empty Imagick object' in /test.php:57
Stack trace:
#0 /test.php(57): Imagick->setimageformat('jpg')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /test.php on line 57

line 57 is  $im->setImageFormat("jpg");
```

However, if I replace my `$im = new Imagick($file)` with `$im = new Imagick('/test/project/test1.pdf'),` the error is gone.

I don't know why this is happening. Can someone give me a hint for this issue? Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @pozs pointed out

> Note 1: Your $file variable is an object SplFileInfo, but you are
>   using it always like a string.

Here's a code snippet which gets you the filename as string and has an optimized method to get the file extension:

```
<?php
    $display           = array ('pdf');
    $directoryIterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('./test/project');

    // The key of the iterator is a string with the filename 
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directoryIterator) as $fileName => $file) {

        // Optimized method to get the file extension
        $fileExtension = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if (in_array(strtolower($fileExtension), $display)) {
            if(file_exists($fileName)){
                echo "{$fileName}\n";

                // Just do what you want with Imagick here
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php), the `.jpg` files' format is `JPEG`.

*Note 1*:

Your `$file` variable is an object `SplFileInfo`, but you are using it always like a string. Use `RecursiveDirectoryIterator::CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME` flag in `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`'s constructor, to be a real string.

*Note 2*:

You can filter the iterator entries with `RegexIterator`, f.ex.: `new RegexIterator($recursiveIteratorIterator, '/\.pdf$/')` (after *Note 1*). Or, you can use `GlobIterator` too for searching only pdf files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this approach from : [PDF to JPG conversion using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624886/pdf-to-jpg-conversion-using-php)

```
$fp_pdf = fopen($pdf, 'rb');

$img = new imagick();
$img->readImageFile($fp_pdf);
```

It also seems from reading other posts that GhostScript is faster?