# PHP FPDF Document to PNG/JPEG

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

I am using `FPDI` to create pdf document,add text and download it in the browser with this code:

```
    $pdf = new FPDI();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($filePath);
    $tppl = $pdf->importPage(1);
    $pdf->useTemplate($tppl, 0, 0, 222.25, 297.18);
    $pdf->SetFont('DejaVu','',10);

    $pdf->SetXY(106,42);
    $pdf->Write(0, date('d'));

    $pdf->SetXY(136,42);
    $pdf->Write(0, date('m'));

    $pdf->Output();
```

And i want to know if there is any way to convert the pdf i create to png/jpeg file and then send it to the user?

Comment: why not send them the pdf?

Comment: Because i am using this to send the pdf to android and in android i am using google docs to show the pdf and it make some problems

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDF to JPG conversion using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624886/pdf-to-jpg-conversion-using-php)

Comment: After generating the PDF you can save it in a temp location and then convert it to a JPG. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624886/pdf-to-jpg-conversion-using-php